# Spring, JPA (Hibernate) & Ehcache Poor Performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, spring, jpa, ehcache

I have what I would assume is a pretty standard setup...spring, jpa (hibernate) and I'm trying to add ehcache.

I have it all configured and verified that it's working...I'm logging the hibernate sql statements and cache statements and can see that the cache is getting invoked and that once the object is in the cache, when I try to load it again, the sql statement is not written out (ie, it's not hitting the database).

However, the performance is terrible...it's pretty much the same performance if I get the object from the cache or from the db. I suspect that perhaps the problem is to do with spring automatically flushing the hibernate session, or maybe the overhead is due to transactions (which I have tried to turn off for that method), or maybe my connection pooling using c3p0 isn't working well enough. At any rate, I'm at a bit of a loss..

I'll post all the relevant information that I have and hopefully some genius here can help me out otherwise I'm stuck.

Firstly, my spring config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:hprof="http://www.nhprof.com/schema/hprof"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http://www.nhprof.com/schema/hprof http://www.nhprof.com/schema/hprof/hprof.xsd">


<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="systemPropertyManager" class="com.service.impl.SystemPropertyManagerImpl" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="mysql" /> 
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>

           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
           <!-- always puts logging out to the console...we want it in the log file -->
           <prop key="hibernate.connection.show_sql">false</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
       <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">500</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1000</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
 <!--   <hprof:profiler /> -->
</bean>


 <bean id="mysql" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/daily?relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&amp;emulateLocators=true" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>5</value></property>
    <property name="minPoolSize"><value>5</value></property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>50</value></property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>200</value></property>
    <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>3</value></property>
    <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>3</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My ehcache file is as follows

```
<ehcache>
<diskStore path="c:/cache"/>

    <defaultCache eternal="false" 
            overflowToDisk="false"
            maxElementsInMemory="50000" 
            timeToIdleSeconds="30" 
            timeToLiveSeconds="6000"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
            />
    <cache name="com.model.SystemProperty"
            maxElementsInMemory="5000"
            eternal="true"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
```

My cached object which is annotated in order to invoke the cache is as follows:

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region="com.model.SystemProperty", include="non-lazy")
@EntityListeners(com.util.GenericEntityLogger.class)
public class SystemProperty extends BaseObject{

    private String name;
    private String value;

    // default constructor
    public SystemProperty(){

    }
    public SystemProperty(String name, String value){
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

and my implementation of my interface used to save and get the SystemProperty object with the spring @Transactional method is as follows:

```
package com.service.impl;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.model.SystemProperty;
import com.service.SystemPropertyManager;


public class SystemPropertyManagerImpl extends BaseManagerImpl implements SystemPropertyManager {

    // logging
    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public SystemProperty find(String name){
        return (SystemProperty) super.entityManager.find(SystemProperty.class, name);
    }

    @Transactional
    public SystemProperty save(SystemProperty prop){
        return (SystemProperty) super.save(prop);
    }

}
```

Note that @Transactional is only on the save method.
Finally, I have populated the mysql database with 3000 system property objects and then have written a little test file, that loads them up twice.

The first time it loads them, I can see the sql being generated and that the cache is not getting hit. The second time, the cache does get hit and the sql isn't generated.

Unit Test:

```
    @Test
public void testGetCachedUser1(){
    log.debug("starting testGetCachedUser");
    SystemPropertyManager mgr = ManagerFactory.getSystemPropertyManager();
    EntityManager em = mgr.getEntityManager();

    log.debug("start timing 1");
    for(int i = 0; i<3000; i ++){
        mgr.find("name_"+i);
    }
    log.debug("end timing 1");
    log.debug("start timing 2");
    for(int i = 0; i<3000; i ++){
        mgr.find("name_"+i);
    }
    log.debug("end timing 2");
}
```

The log file has lots of info. I'll post the section from the log file in the "start timing 1" area. This corresponds to what happens only for the very first object that is loaded when it's not in the cache:

```
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [find] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 5274603804807168
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4e2f0a [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1631573)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,533 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - after transaction begin
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@5fbbf3] for key [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 31ghzi8b1mphf1c19l14qo|149105b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 31ghzi8b1mphf1c19l14qo|149105b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 200, initialPoolSize -> 5, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/daily?relaxAutoCommit=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&emulateLocators=true, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] to thread [main]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1bb03ee] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@11b99c4] to thread [main]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Initializing transaction synchronization
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [com.service.SystemPropertyManager.find]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1bb03ee] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@11b99c4] bound to thread [main]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - loading entity: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - attempting to resolve: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - object not resolved in any cache: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Fetching entity: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - loading entity: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.SQL - select systemprop0_.name as name11_0_, systemprop0_.value as value11_0_ from SystemProperty systemprop0_ where systemprop0_.name=?
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,549 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - preparing statement
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'name_0' to parameter: 1
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - processing result set
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result set row: 0
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Initializing object from ResultSet: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Hydrating entity: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning 'value_0' as column: value11_0_
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done processing result set (1 rows)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - closing statement
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 1
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,580 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - adding entity to second-level cache: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.cache.ReadOnlyCache - Caching: com.model.SystemProperty#name_0
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done entity load
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [com.service.SystemPropertyManager.find]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - commit
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - automatically flushing session
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - flushing session
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.model.SystemProperty
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.engine.Cascade - done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: com.model.SystemProperty
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing unreferenced collections
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - listing entities:
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.pretty.Printer - com.model.SystemProperty{name=name_0, value=value_0}
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - executing flush
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - registering flush begin
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - registering flush end
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - post flush
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - before transaction completion
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - before transaction completion
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - after transaction completion
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4e2f0a [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1631573)
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - after transaction completion
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Clearing transaction synchronization
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,596 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@1bb03ee] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@11b99c4] from thread [main]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,612 [main][] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@5fbbf3] for key [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 31ghzi8b1mphf1c19l14qo|149105b, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 31ghzi8b1mphf1c19l14qo|149105b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 200, initialPoolSize -> 5, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/daily?relaxAutoCommit=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&emulateLocators=true, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]] from thread [main]
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,612 [main][] org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - closing session
DEBUG 2010-10-22 11:57:49,612 [main][] org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - connection already null in cleanup : no action
```

You can see that it's getting loaded into the cache, the hibernate session is opened and closed and flushed.

I'll post my second log file in a comment below as I've hit the max length already of this question. Main point is, it all looks ok, the only real problem is that it's sooo damn slow.

When I load 3000 objects the first time (ie, hitting the db) it takes pretty much exactly the same as teh second time (ie, hitting the cache). Like I said, is it cos the overhead is opening and closing the connection, flushing the session, dealing with transactions? I'm not sure. But it's pretty brutal at any rate. Help me stackoverflow...you're my only hope :)

Comment: I can't seem to add another comment which shows enough detail of my second log file. Suffice to say that it's exactly the same as the first time except that it does hit the cache. Eg, snippit:

Comment: If you need to attach more logs/code, http://pastebin.com/ is very useful

Comment: org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - resolved object in second-level cache: [com.model.SystemProperty#name_0]
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [com.service.SystemPropertyManager.find]
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - commit
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - automatically flushing session

Comment: thanks skaffman - http://pastebin.com/96ZSiHvG this is the second log file that shows that the sql isn't getting hit but rather the cache is correctly invoked in the second iteration of the loop in the unit test.

Comment: Ok, some interesting updates...firstly, if I've got average stats for run 1 (hit the db) and run 2 (don't). Over 3000 selects, run 1 averages around 16ms and run 2 averages the exact same. Interestingly, if I remove spring transactions that drops us down to only 2ms...still however it's the same on the two runs...cache and non cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Main point is, it all looks ok, the only real problem is that it's sooo damn slow.

*Damn slow* is a subjective measurement unit :)

> When I load 3000 objects the first time (ie, hitting the db) it takes pretty much exactly the same as the second time (ie, hitting the cache).

Show metrics, without all the logging overhead (and also without P6Spy), using [`System.nanoTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Maybe also try to perform your test inside a single transaction, using a single `EntityManager`, just to see how things behave in these conditions.

> Like I said, is it cos the overhead is opening and closing the connection, flushing the session, dealing with transactions? I'm not sure. But it's pretty brutal at any rate.

Can't say, you should profile your code to see where the time is spent (and also monitor the GC activity).

But in theory:

- The `connection` in a `Session` is lazy (will get acquired only when required)
- Acquiring a `connection` from C3P0 should be pretty fast (negligible)
- Since your entities are cached as read-only, the `flush` should be pretty fast

In other words, I wouldn't expect the above operations to be expensive (so I'd focus on the surrounding parts). But as I said, profile (and monitor the GC activity).

Comment: All good sensible points Pascal. Ok, for Run 1 (Hitting the DB), average time for each load across the 3,000 in nanoseconds 18,029,219 versus for Run 2: 16,610,083. Now, if I remove spring transactions that becomes: 2,520,817 for run 1 vs 498,435 for run 2 which does show good improvements. But basically, it implies that adding spring transactions are a significant overhead. I'll profile the app as you suggested to confirm. Thanks very much

Comment: @Brian Good, at least you know what is **not** taking time now. I'm just amazed that spring transactions are so expensive, especially given that your read method is not `@Transactional` annotated. As a side note, you might enjoy [Transaction strategies: Understanding transaction pitfalls](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1.html) (this won't really help you though, but it's a good reading).

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for your comments on this one. I was amazed too that they were so expensive. Profiling confirmed that the transactions were the expensive issue. Changing the propogation parameter to Supports from Requires_New helped a bit. Appreciate all your help. Brian

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest trying to replace that 2nd level cache usage with plain applicative cache. When I tested Hibernate's 2nd level cache performance in the past, I noticed it wasn't very effective. This is due to the way the cached data is structured - similar to a result set - that is tabular data is being store, and not objects. This means many many cache requests, which turns out to be expensive.

In order to separate the cache code from the persistence logic, I use AOP. Since you use Spring this should be easy.

Comment: The measurements made by the OP show that the L2 cache is fully doing its job, in an effective way. That's not the problem at all. And while having to rehydrate entities with tabular data from the cache (vs storing entities in a cache) might have a little overhead, this is certainly still negligible vs a (even local) database access. I'd really like to have details about your bench, the cache implementation used, the configuration, the order of magnitude... To my experience, Hibernate L2 cache API is pretty effective.

Comment: @Pascal, In my prev working place, we performed several tests - Hibernate 2nd level caching VS applicative caching using an AOP interceptor we wrote, on top of our service layer. That is, the caching also prevented starting a TX, and acquiring a connection. I conducted one of these tests, after another developer reported bad performance from the 2nd level cache. The results were pretty much similar to what OP is describing, and the applicative caching strategy showed superior performance, in an order of magnitude. I no longer have access to the results, but it's easy to recreate...

Comment: @Eran Very interesting, adding this to my todo list (although I still think the problem is more related to the TX demarcation). Thanks for answering.

Comment: BTW, this does not mean that Hibernate's 2nd level cache is not good for DB hit avoidance.

Comment: @Eran very interesting indeed and thanks for your comments. It's very surprising and interesting that the hibernate implementations were poor in comparison to the home rolled one. Perhaps it is, as you partially suggest, the lack of transactions, and the connection acquiring that makes the difference. It's very surprising that hibernate doesn't also do this however. Thanks for the interesting comments on it anyway guys. At least it's more performant then it was at the start. :)

Comment: 10X @Brain. Please share your final solution. Others will be interested.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you are not hitting database in your cache call? enable hibernate sql debug logger to see if it is doing the right thing. I never used entity manager before. I always use the hibernate session. If you enable query cache, you still have to do setCache(true) in the hibernate query. Otherwise, it will still hit the db. The @Cache annotation in the entity only cache it by id in ehcache. When you set your query to be cacheable, the cache key is your query and result is the entity id, then it will try to resolve the entity in the ehcache by id.

Answer (score 2):

Your test uses the EntityManager directly without a transaction. An EntityManager is scoped to a single unit of work, typically a single transaction. You're probably forcing a new transaction incl. the lookup in the pool of a DB connection for every find invocation.

Here's what I would suggest:

- use read-only transactions for the non-save methods instead of no TX demarcation
- wrap your DataSource bean in a LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy to avoid getting a Connection if you don't actually need to talk to your database (i.e. in case of a cache hit)
- update your test to talk to your service bean instead of directly using an EntityManager.